# Can't load image with OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, javacv

I tried to use `Imgcodecs.imread` from OpenCV on Android to an load image which is located in the drawable folder, but when I check the data of the image, it is `null`.

This is my simple code to load image:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mImageRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();

    img_object = Imgcodecs.imread("D:\\Project_Android\\Car_Tracking_1\\app\\src\\main\\res\\drawable\\rear_of_car.png");
    Log.i("aaa2", img_object.dump());

    return mImageRGBA;
}
```

This is the logcat info from that function:

```
06-26 00:27:15.056 24939-25059/com.example.bruce.car_tracking_1 I/aaa2: []
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Am I finding the path incorrectly? Or am I loading the image incorrectly?

**SOLVED:**

Hello all i solved my problem by another way. So many thank to sturkmen for your attempt help

I use load image from drawable folder, this image is a bitmap and show it in screen and then i convert it to Mat to use it futher. :) Here is my complete code.

first,create 2 global variable

```
ImageView imageview;
Bitmap icon;
```

Then,

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Resources res = getResources();
                icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.rear_of_car);// get data from drawable folder 
                imageview.setImageBitmap(icon); // show data in imageview of screen
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default: {super.onManagerConnected(status);} break;
        }
    }
};

public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    img_object = new Mat(157, 140, CvType.CV_8UC1);
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mImageRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(icon, img_object);//convert image bitmap to Mat to use it futher
    Log.i("aaa", String.valueOf(img_object.cols()));
    Log.i("aaa1", String.valueOf(img_object.rows()));
    return mImageRGBA;
}
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    img_object.release();
}
```

remember add Image view in activity_main.xml

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

and put your image to drawable folder

[image]

Comment: is that path present in your android system? Isnt android limited to linux pathes?

Comment: Hello Berriel, path of image is in drawable folder , in my computer(not located in sd card or phone memory). I don't understand second question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to be sure that your path is valid try to write a test image

```
Mat test = new Mat(3,3,0);
Imgcodecs.imwrite("D:\\Project_Android\\Car_Tracking_1\\app\\src\\main\\res\\drawable\\test.png",test);
```

if you can save the image you can also load it.

edit:
also you can try like

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
mImageRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();

img_object = Imgcodecs.imread("D:\\Project_Android\\Car_Tracking_1\\app\\src\\main\\res\\drawable\\rear_of_car.png");
Imgcodecs.imwrite("D:\\Project_Android\\Car_Tracking_1\\app\\src\\main\\res\\drawable\\test.png",img_object);
Log.i("aaa2", img_object.dump());

return mImageRGBA;
```

}

edit 2:

please try

```
img_object = Imgcodecs.imread("D:\\Project_Android\\Car_Tracking_1\\app\\src\\main\\res\\drawable\\rear_of_car.png");
Imgcodecs.imwrite("D:\\Project_Android\\Car_Tracking_1\\app\\src\\main\\res\\drawable\\test.png",img_object);
```

instead of

```
Mat test = new Mat(3,3,0);
Imgcodecs.imwrite("D:\\Project_Android\\Car_Tracking_1\\app\\src\\main\\res\\drawable\\test.png",test);
```

Comment: Hi sturkmen, It's run :) But i don't know why Mat test had to a local variable. I used to use this way but my Mat img_object is a global variable. It is created in public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) { img_object = new Mat(157, 140, CvType.CV_8UC1); }   and release in public void onCameraViewStopped() {img_object.release();} Could you please explain , with my way, why doesn't it run??

Comment: @Bruce sorry i am not familiar with JAVA environment. could you try my edited answer and report the result?

Comment: first, i see data of Mat test in logcat, but then when i check it, data is not my image, it just a back image with some white point :( i am still  not get my image

Comment: Mat test is just for check if the path is valid. yes it is a 3x3 blank image. what about second test. you will get an error when you try to save if your image is not loaded.

Comment: My path is valid, path of image is located in my computer, and i try to load it but it seem to not load with Imgcodecs.imwrite, do you have another way to load image from my computer to android studio

Comment: sorry I am confused. tell me what happened when you try my edited answer.

Comment: With you edited, i see in logcat a matrix 3x3 with randon number, it not my image, my image have size 157x140

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115614/discussion-between-sturkmen-and-bruce).

Comment: I was try use it but i still get img_object.cols and img_object.row is null